# Potential due to a dipole placed at the centre of a sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, dipole-moment

Recently I came across a question which stated that a **small** electric dipole is placed at the centre of a sphere(insulated). I'm required to prove that the potential due to this dipole is *always zero* on a **circle on the surface of the sphere.** What does *a circle on the surface of a sphere* mean here? Is it the planar section cut off by a plane and a sphere? I know that for an **equatorial point** with respect to a dipole, potential is always zero. But how can a circle be always at an equatorial position with respect to the *dipole at the centre of sphere*? Can someone help me in this and illustrate it using a diagram?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may already have the correct intuition here. If the dipole is oriented towards the north pole of the sphere, the circle around the **equator** of the sphere (i.e. if you draw a line all the way around the sphere at the equator) has a potential of zero.

A intuitive argument for **why** the potential is zero is easy: in the plane perpendicular to the dipole moment, the electric field is always antiparallel to the dipole moment, so if you were moving a charge $q$ in from $r=\infty$ toward the dipole, the work done by the electric field would be $\vec E \cdot \vec{dl}=0$ because $\vec E$ is always perpendicular to $\vec{dl}$.

The field of a dipole $\vec p$ at position $\vec R$:
$$ \vec E (\vec R) = \frac{3 (\vec p \cdot \hat R) \hat R - \vec p }{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^3}$$
If we set $\vec p = p_0 \hat z $ and $\vec R = r \hat x$, then we get
$$ \vec E = \frac{3 p_0 (\hat z \cdot \hat x) \hat x - p_0 \hat z }{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^3} = -\frac{ p_0 \hat z }{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^3} $$

For any point final point $\vec R_f = r_f \hat x$, with $\vec{dl} = dR \hat x$ the potential is

$$ V = - \int \limits_{\infty}^{r_f} \vec E \cdot \vec{dl} = \int \limits_{\infty}^{r_f} \frac{ p_0 \hat z \cdot dR \hat x }{4\pi \epsilon_0 R^3} = 0 $$

Comment: I get it now, thanks a lot! I was having a tough time trying to visualize things!

Comment: Sorry to disturb, but I'm having yet another confusion. How do we get a circle in this case? I can only think of a line perpendicular to the dipole and passing through its centre.

Comment: The circle is the equator of the sphere